# Reflector issue when decompiling a WPF assembly (i.e. PresentationCore, PresentationFramework)

Tags: wpf, reflector

I just downloaded the last version of Reflector from RedGate and I was unable to decompile classes in some core WPF assemblies like PresentationCore and PresentationFramework.

Here is a link to a picture that describes my problem:

http://997966480542455630-a-1802744773732722657-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/badrdocs/files/Reflector_issue.png?attachauth=ANoY7cqzFOr_iIPHnS2V67hKSpxXdlr4B0fOh7u2pzWImgJp6QKELErlVpOoCkDP3IVd4zvbnCBDWHXw-hY_eeGu5UUqWiuW5bbAb2YDTETnZYJ3bMvfN6WF28u2ERar9DcjeuqXslKt1bv7SY8dW82da0ndleAaoBDBe0QuY1jHVfOPK4HkXqpZOqKF0nMZNCP36rhFkBgzdG8SSYnA4YwKmYwD_mS2Kg%3D%3D&attredirects=1

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, this is your problem (I know because I had the same issue):

There are some assemblies that, for whatever reason, can't disassemble (its as if they are empty).  These assemblies are (sorry, memory here) under the Program Files directory somewhere.

You need to open the same assemblies but under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\etc\etc.

Comment: For future reference, if you see assemblies under "Reference Assemblies" directory in program files, these assemblies are special metadata-only versions for use by Visual Studio for multitargeting support.  They are not the actual assemblies with code.

Comment: the location on my machine is C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF

Answer (score 0):

What version do you have? I'm using 6.1.0.11 (apparently the latest) and I get the following:

```
protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
{
    return new ListBoxItem();
}
```

If you're not seeing that, I would suggest a better place to ask would be the [RedGate forums](http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewforum.php?f=85).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're using an older version of Reflector to inspect .NET 4.0 assemblies... I had this problem too, but the latest version of Reflector fixes it.

Comment: I have the last version (6.1), I downloaded it today.

Comment: .NET 4.0 language support has only been added in the early access builds for 6.5. They're available here:

http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?t=10835