# Why can I not decompile the DataRowExtensions methods with .NET Reflector?

Tags: .net, reflection, casting, extension-methods

When I load

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll

in .NET Reflector (soon to be replaced by ILSpy), and open `System.Data.DataRowExtensions`, when I look at the method `Field<T>(DataRow,DataColumn):T`, the C# source code is just:

```
public static T Field<T>(this DataRow row, DataColumn column)
{
}
```

I was expecting to see at least one line of code in the method like:

```
return (T)row[column];
```

Why would the method appear empty as in the first code example?

Comment: I read somewhere "The Field extension method as shown in this article will internally invoke a generic method that validates the parameter, then uses a generic method to unbox the object inside the DataTable. Because no copying of the actual data will take place for reference types, the Field extension method will have adequate performance."

Comment: Or you could just go to the reference source online at referencesource.microsoft.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assemblies in `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies` are for "reference" only, and are used by Visual Studio to [support multi-targeting](http://mokosh.co.uk/post/2010/06/05/net-reflector-showing-empty-implementation/). The don't generally contain any implementation details, just the members.

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845950/reflector-issue-when-decompiling-a-wpf-assembly-i-e-presentationcore-presentat) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239320/reflector-not-decompiling-system-data-entity-dll-net-4-0).

You would need to load the real assembly to see the implementation. Generally, when debugging you can see where the assemblies are located, if you can't find them.

Answer (score 1):

I can see the method in both

- C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
- C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll

.

```
public static T Field<T>(this DataRow row, DataColumn column)
{
    DataSetUtil.CheckArgumentNull<DataRow>(row, "row");
    return UnboxT<T>.Unbox(row[column]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I can also see the implementation details at those locations, but I was looking for a rational explanation for why I couldn't see them in the specific assembly I loaded.